# Big-O of a small loop

Tags: algorithm, search, big-o

I have a problem with an exercise I have to do for Uni, it is the following:

> This function receives a string s and returns true if s contains the
>   two first letters of the given string sub (in lowercase and in any
>   order). Otherwise, it returns false.
>
> Some examples: Let's say that sub = "Euler", then it checks for 'e'
>   and 'u'. Thus,
>          s = "may the force be with you", then return true.
>          s = "the room 31", then return false.
>          s = "un93ike1s", then return true.
>
> Choose the tightest (worst-case time) complexity of the following
>   lines.
>
> ```
> function contains_two_letters(s, sub, n)
>
> /* create a vector with two entries, both set to false */ 
> found = [ false, false ]               (1)
>
> for (i = 0; i < n; i++)                (2)
>     for (k = 0; k < 2; k++)            (3)
>         if s[i] == sub[k]:             (4)
>             found[k] = true
>             break
> return (found[0] and found[1])
> ```

I know/suppose that:
**(1)** is O(1),

**(2)** is O(n) and

**(4)** is O(1),

but what about **(3)**?

**Problem**: We never saw an example of a loop that only runs twice, so I assume it is O(2) but that isn't an option in the drop-down.

The available options are O(n), O(1), O(n^2) and O(log(n))

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Big-O isn't directly about the performance or number of operations in an algorithm: it's all about tracking the way that the number of operations *changes* as the problem size increases.

If there's a loop which doesn't happen more times as `n` grows toward infinity, then that loop is constant-time, and simplifies down to `O(1)`. It doesn't matter how expensive it is, or how many times it happens. It could iterate a million times, but if increasing `n` doesn't impact it, it's still `O(1)`.

Line 3 in your problem, therefore, is `O(1)`, and Line 2 (and the overall function) is `O(n)` because the outer loop is the only one that happens more often as `n` increases.